# Getting Duplicate function implementation Error in VS code intellisense

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I was learning about typescript but I am getting this duplicate function implementation problem in vs code intellisense whenever I open two different files having same function name but when I close one of the files the error goes away and there is also no errors present when I compile both the files.

[image]
[image]

Now when I close one of the files the error goes away.
[image]

I searched this problem but solutions were for projects and included some tsconfig.json file but here I am just learning the language not doing any projects.

What is happening here? And how can I remove this problem.

Comment: don't put your `.js` files in the same dir as your `.ts` files, `.ts` files in `/src` and `.js` files in `/out`

Comment: copy the text of the files and not images, just mention the relative path and then the source

Answer (score 0):

Your files do not have static imports or exports, making them ambient files. Similar to how when you link multiple JS files to your HTML without type=module, everything in your files shares one namespace. To fix this, add `export {}` to each of your files, making them modules with their own namespace.

```
// ...

export {}; // now a module with own namespace
```

---

What I mean by "ambient":

```js
// foo.js
const x = 42;
```

```js
// bar.js
console.log(x); // x is available in this file
```

```html
<script src="foo.js"></script> // since you link it here
<script src="bar.js"></script>
```

---

Alternatively, I see that you are lacking a `tsconfig.json`, which is the source of two issues:

- the one you are asking about now (conflicting declarations)
- compiled js files being in the same folder as your ts files

Making a `tsconfig.json` will solve *both* of these. You can get started with that [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).